# Kubernetes/AWS - ELB is not deleted when the service is deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm using the `--cloud-provider=aws` flag to integrate Kubernetes with AWS. I'm able to create and expose a service via ELB using the following commands:

```
kubectl run sample-nginx --image=docker.io/nginx --port=80

kubectl expose deployment/sample-nginx --port=80 --target-port=80 \
--name=sample-nginx-service --type=LoadBalancer && \
kubectl annotate svc sample-nginx-service \
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal=0.0.0.0/0
```

This exposes the nginx service on an internal-ELB on a private subnet. I'm able to access the service on the ELB as well.

Now, when I delete the service, the service is deleted, but the ELB is not. Here's how I deleted the service:

```
kubectl delete services sample-nginx-service
```

Any pointers to what could be going wrong? I did not see any errors in the `kube-controller-manager` log when I ran the deletion command. What other logs should I be checking?

Comment: What `kubectl` and `controller` versions are you running?

Comment: Kubernetes 1.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to etcd `v3.0.17` from `v3.0.10` fixed the issue. I found another log messaged in the controller logs which pointed to the issue here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41760

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo on your service delete command.

It should be `kubectl delete services sample-nginx-service`.

I just tried this on my AWS cluster and confirmed that the ELB was deleted successfully after running this.

I'm running Kubernetes 1.6.2 with kubectl 1.6.3

Comment: I had actually made a typo when I wrote the answer - the command I ran was actually `sample-nginx-service` instead of `sample-nginx`.

Comment: Your updated answer `kubectl delete services sample-nginx-sample-nginx-service` still wouldn't work.

Comment: Would be useful to provide the ouput of `kubectl describe svc,deployment,pod -lrun=sample-nginx` after you delete your service as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the same process but with a config file and see if it's command or config related?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but to no avail. It turned out to be an issue with the etcd version I was using. Upgrading it solved the problem.